# GenBank to FASTA format using regular expressions without Biopython

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, bioinformatics

This is a Biopython alternative with pretty straightforward code. How can I make this more concise?

```
def genbank_to_fasta():
    file = input(r'Input the path to your file: ')
    with open(f'{file}') as f:
        gb = f.readlines()
        locus = re.search('NC_\d+\.\d+', gb[3]).group()
        region = re.search('(\d+)?\.+(\d+)', gb[2])
        definition = re.search('\w.+', gb[1][10:]).group()
        definition = definition.replace(definition[-1], "")
        tag = locus + ":" + region.group(1) + "-" + region.group(2) + " " + definition
        sequence = ""
        for line in (gb):
            pattern = re.compile('[a,t,g,c]{10}')
            matches = pattern.finditer(line)
            for match in matches:
                sequence += match.group().upper()
        end_pattern = re.search('[a,t,g,c]{1,9}', gb[-3])
        sequence += end_pattern.group().upper()
        print(len(sequence))
        return sequence, tag
```

Comment: @Emma here is an example. 'REGION: 26156329..26157115'

Comment: @Emma Those numbers are not always 8 digits long it depends. Here are the links for the reference I use. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_000006.12?report=genbank&from=26156329&to=26157115 (GenBank file)  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NC_000006.12?report=fasta&from=26156329&to=26157115 (FASTA file).

Comment: @Emma that's good to know. My main problem came with the sequence. If the last group of DNA was not a group of 10, my current code will not parse it so I had to write the end_pattern pattern in order to get the last one. I think there is a better way to do it but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the order of the size of the input files? Kilobytes? Gigabytes?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I believe it is in kilobytes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Line iteration

```
    gb = f.readlines()
    locus = re.search('NC_\d+\.\d+', gb[3]).group()
    region = re.search('(\d+)?\.+(\d+)', gb[2])
    definition = re.search('\w.+', gb[1][10:]).group()

    for line in (gb):
        # ...
    end_pattern = re.search('[a,t,g,c]{1,9}', gb[-3])
```

can be

```
next(f)
definition = re.search('\w.+', next(f)[10:]).group()
region = re.search('(\d+)?\.+(\d+)', next(f))
locus = re.search('NC_\d+\.\d+', next(f)).group()

gb = tuple(f)

for line in gb:
```

Since you need `gb[-3]`, you can't get away with a purely "streamed" iteration. You could be clever and keep a small queue of the last few entries you've read, if you're deeply worried about memory consumption.

### Debugging statements

Remove this:

```
    print(len(sequence))
```

or convert it to a logging call at the debug level.

### Compilation

Do not do this:

```
        pattern = re.compile('[a,t,g,c]{10}')
```

in an inner loop. The whole point of `compile` is that it can be done once to save the cost of re-compilation; so a safe option is to do this at the global level instead.